# C# Difference between Nested classes vs child class without Polymorphism

Tags: c#, inheritance, nested, inner-classes

Lets say C2 is a C1, and I need C2 to have access to M1, and C1 to not have access to M2. If I dont need Polymorphism, would the following code do the exact same thing as me doing the same thing without nested classes, but instead using Inheritance?

```
class C1 {
  protected void M1() {
    \\code
  class C2 {
  private void M2() {
      \\code
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't have access to `C1.M1` from nested `C2`.

Comment: Feels like a bad design (no offense). What exactly you want to do?

Comment: So the parent class' fields and methods are not accessible by the child class?

Comment: It's not a "parent" actually. `C2` just sits inside `C1` but there is no relationship between them.

Comment: You can't define `C2` inside `M1`. You can only define `C2` inside `C1` next to `M1`.

Comment: So, in this case having the nested class not be a nested claas wouldnt change anything, then, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial example is syntactically incorrect:

```
class C1 {
  protected void M1() {
    \\code
  class C2 {
  private void M2() {
      \\code
     }
  }
}
```

You can't define the `C2` class inside the `M1` method.

---

Another question that you asked in the comments (rephrased):

> Why do we need nested classes at all?

The only thing a can come up with is such case:

```
    public class C1
    {
        public void M1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType()}.M1()");

            var c2 = new C2();
            c2.M2();
        }

        private class C2
        {
            public void M2()
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{this.GetType()}.M2()");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c1 = new C1();
            c1.M1();
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ClassesExample.C1.M1()
> ClassesExample.C1+C2.M2()

We have a private `C2` class which is only accessible from inside of `C1`. I don't know why would I do this. But if it's really needed, that's the usage of a nested class.